# Is magento compatible for GDPR compliance

Tags: gdpr

I want to know is magento compatible for GDPR compliance because from May 25, 2018 GDPR Act is applied in all EU countries.

What should we need to do to run our magento e-commerce site under this rule.

Comment: Good question. Only came to know about this now.

Comment: as far as i checked, it wont be. We might need to make it compliant.

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer is NO, Magento is not yet GDPR compliance, but you need to bear in mind GDPR is not just implementing technical elements on your website or Magento store. It is a disciple which is around making sure the personal data (for example email address, phone number, name, addresss, medical info etc.) which is stored in your datacentre in any format or the personal data that you are sharing with third parties is secure.

Here is the list of things you need to consider to answer -:

- What information is being collected?
- Who is collecting it?
- How is it collected?
- Why is it being collected?
- How will it be used?
- Who will it be shared with?
- What will be the effect of this on the individuals concerned?
- Is the intended use likely to cause individuals to object or complain?

Here is the list of things which could help you achieving GDPR compliance on your Magento store -:

- Move all your trackings to Google Tag Manager
- Adds cookie consent toolbar either on the header and footer of your website
- Ability to remove personal data by individuals
- Ability to Opt-out from subscription by individuals
- Ability to export personal data
- Anonymize personal data, especially the data which is not being used for transactional purposes for example data sitting in quote table
- Update privacy policy
- Security scan

Please have a look at the following page which can help around GDPR compliance on Magento store -:

https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-gdpr-compliance.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information, do we have any third party extensions available to achieve this?

Comment: the above link will give you all the information needed but you can install the following extension for Magento 1 https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento1-gdpr-compliance.html which covers right to be forgotten, right to be informed and right of access.

Comment: @sv3n - I have covered remove/anonymisation in point 3 and 6 above. In regards to "minimize collection of data" that could vary business to business for example some business do need phone number to call before they deliver goods. As far as they can justify why are they collecting personal data then it should be ok.

Comment: @joshua-flood - Once your order has been delivered, then you don't need this data which means you can anonymise it. As a business you should have a data retention policy in place which could be between 6 months to 10 years which means after that period all personal data will be either deleted or anoymised. This will hugely reduce the impact in case the data gets stolen. Hope this helps.

Comment: @user2804 - here is the link to M2 extension as well https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento2-gdpr-compliance.html#product-customer-reviews

Answer (score 4):

General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) is all about making customer data secure. 
 After searching on google I have found some useful links and module as below:

https://github.com/AdfabConnect/magento2gdpr (Module provides GPDR compliance inside Magento2)

https://www.aitoc.com/blog/gdpr-compliance-magento-security-tips/

https://community.magento.com/t5/Off-Topic/GDPR-Compliance-for-those-with-EU-customers/td-p/66781

Hope this help!!

Answer (score 1):

Today I also searching for the GDPR extension and found that extensions are available on Magento marketplace.

M1: https://marketplace.magento.com/zero1-zero1-gdpr.html

M2: https://marketplace.magento.com/zero1-gdpr.html

Answer (score 0):

GDPR introduces some significant changes in the data protection laws to help tighten security of citizens’ information online. The regulation consequently gives a strong impact on how companies collect and process personal data.
If you just need the basic features to follow the GDPR you can download it for free here: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-gdpr. If you need more than that(Manage billing documents, Cookie restriction...) look Pro version at this: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-gdpr-extension/